# Is there another controversial statement by Grothendieck apart from 57 being prime?

Tags: ho.history-overview, transcendental-number-theory, fractions

There is a well-known story about Grothendieck being asked to explain concretely some result involving prime numbers and of his answering  "You mean an actual number? All right, take 57".
See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326912/story-of-grothendiecks-prime-number-57).
Unfortunately there seems to be no written trace of this anecdote and it it is not clear whether it happened or not.
But did he make a **written** assertion in the same vein?

Comment: Possibly you're joking, but this is not of a "controversy" but just thoughtlessness, and, in the written example $344/133$, just a careless typo. Fortunately not every typo by an important mathematician is a controversy.

Comment: Dear @YCor: yes, it had not escaped my attention that there is no actual controversy about 57 being or not prime nor about 344/133 being or not a good approximation of $\pi$...

Comment: In Grothendieck's paper [Hodge's general conjecture is false for trivial reasons](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938369900160) example the last paragraph on page 300 before the start of section 2.

I believe that every statement in that paragraph is in some way incorrect. There is a typographical error in line 1. In line 2 he asserts something about the vector space generated $j$-fold products of distinct elements of a collection of complex numbers which is incorrect without additional assumptions.... contd. below

Comment: ... contd. The last sentence seems to work for some $\tau$ but not all of them.

Note that this paper is not "controversial". Indeed, it is very insightful. It is just curious that when providing a concrete example (or as concrete as it gets with G!), there are numerous inaccuracies which one would not expect! One can work out the example he "means" to write and it is indeed an example of the type he wants.

Comment: By "controversial statement" do you mean a purely mathematical one? Because otherwise [the list would not be short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck#Political_activism).

Comment: @polfosol: I couldn't find a single controversial statement in the list.

Comment: @Franz "_He wrote that he and other established mathematicians had no need for additional financial support and criticized what he saw as the declining ethics of the scientific community that was characterized by outright scientific theft that he believed had become commonplace and tolerated_". I find the first sentence to be highly controversial. But I think it's the nature of a controversial statement that some might not consider it as one.

Comment: @polfosol "But I think it's the nature of a controversial statement that some might not consider it as one." Ah, that's an amusing but profound remark!

Answer (score 33):

Yes, he did.
In his  [*Récoltes et semailles, volume I*](https://www.amazon.fr/RECOLTES-SEMAILLES-Alexandre-Grothendieck/dp/2072889758/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_pl_foot_top?ie=UTF8) posthumously edited by Gallimard in 2022 he reminisces (in footnote 68, page 522) about his first encounter with $\pi$ as a child:

"*La valeur approchée 344/133 trouvée dans un livre (...) m'avait frappé-elle était si jolie que j'avais du mal à croire qu'elle ne soit qu'approchée!*"
which I translate as:
"*The approximate value 344/133 found in a book (...) had struck me-it was so pretty that I could hardly believe that it was only approximate !*"

This is interesting because $344/133=2.586466...$, certainly the worst approximation of $\pi$ in the history of Mathematics!
Needless to to say his unnamed book certainly had $\pi\cong355/113=3.14159...$, with all digits correct.
What I find amusing is that neither Grothendieck in his fifties when he wrote *Récoltes et semailles*, nor the people at Gallimard, nor the numerous mathematicians who retyped the manuscript, nor any of my colleagues who read the book noticed this egregious blunder...
As a bonus, here is the [retyped manuscript](https://jmrlivres.files.wordpress.com/2009/11/recoltes-et-semailles.pdf) , with the footnote on page 318.

Comment: Not surprising since many mathematicians are apparently averse to giving actual numerical results, doing numerical checks, etc., preferring to deal mostly only with algebraic proxies/expressions and tossing about theorems.

Comment: That's *arithmetic*, not *mathematics*. I tried to drill the difference into my school age kids - they never got it.

Comment: [This isn't even the worst approximation of $\pi$ on the StackExchanges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4)

Comment: I guess Serre's *Course in Arithmetic* is not mathematics, then...